# Why won't my function get called up after my Ajax event OR on (document).ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a javaScript function called `embedAmplienceModules()` which is sat in an external js file that needs calling for certain promo banners on our site that have a class called ‘amplience-module’. This javaScript enables functionality to work on these banners that was created inside a 3rd party partner called Amplience, like slideshows, digital catalogues, hot spot links on lifestyle images that link directly through to products etc.

This script needs loading after either of the two events occur:

1. A click on a category option in the side nav which refreshes the page content via Ajax.
2. A click on a banner which links through to a category page which causes a page refresh.

ISSUE: 
The problem is, my script gets loaded successfully via option 1 above but not option 2. It only loads the script once. So if I have three Amplience promo banners present the script only loads for the last one. I have tried wrapping the call to my `embedAmplienceModules()` function inside a `(document).ready` but this doesn't work.

In another external javaScript file which is used for all global site js, we have an Ajax event handler and within this is the call to my `embedAmplienceModules()` function, which works fine after the Ajax event/refresh.

Below is the content of the javaScript file. The call to this file is sat within the `<head>` tag of the site.

```
function embedAmplienceModules() {

$('.amplience-module').each(function() {

    var divId = $(this).attr('id'); // div id eg.'amp-m1-area'
    var ampId = $(this).data("ampid"); // Pulls amp id eg. 'eba2d785-f2c1-494f-8f92-b3d95dff80f8' from 'data-ampid' attribute in contentmodules.html template
    var ampDimWidth = $(this).data("ampdimwidth"); // Pulls amp module width eg. '747' from 'data-ampdimwidth' attribute in contentmodules.html template
    var ampDimHeight = $(this).data("ampdimheight"); // Pulls amp module height eg. '241' from 'data-ampdimheight' attribute in contentmodules.html template
    var ampBaseDir = $(this).data("ampbasedir"); // Pulls player file path from 'data-ampbasedir' attribute in contentmodules.html template
    var options = { 
        target: divId,
        width: ampDimWidth,
        height: ampDimHeight,
        vars: {id: ampId, resolveJSPath:"true"},
        params: {allowScriptAccess: "always", base: ampBaseDir, deepLinking:"false",wmode: "transparent"},
        src: [
          {type:"html5", src: ampBaseDir+"tcplayer.js", xd: [ampBaseDir+"xd.html"]},
          {type:"swf", src: ampBaseDir+"tcplayer.swf",version:"9.0.0"}
      ]
    };

    options = $.extend(options);

    interact.embedApp(options);   // the actual Amplience library call

    $(this).removeClass("amplience-module"); // remove the amplienceModule class so this does not get run again for this module later. Must have this. 

});

}
```

This is the html which uses data-XXX attributes to store the appropriate information based on details entered in the back end for the particular Amplience banner. I have removed some conditional values here to make it easier to understand. These are pulled in based on values entered into the back end against the category.

```
<div id="amp-m1-area" class="amplience-module" data-ampid="eba2d785-f2c1-494f-8f92-b3d95dff80f8" data-ampdimwidth="241" data-ampdimheight="241" data-ampbasedir="path/to/amp/directory"></div>
```

The loading order is:

1. File containing my `embedAmplienceModules()` function
2. Content i.e. HTML containing data-XXX atts
3. Global js file containing call to `embedAmplienceModules()` function for Ajax event

Any ideas on why this function won't load on (document).ready?

** ANSWER**
I removed the 'options = $.extend(options);' line and it worked!

Comment: Is anything at all happening in your document ready?

Comment: Describes awesomely good! Can you add your code to fork?

Comment: @MrUpsidown No nothing. After a page refresh, the result doesn't change. Only 1 content module will have the loaded script if I have the function call inside the document ready or if i don't have a document ready present at all and this module will be the last one present (if there is more than one). There are lots of other functions sat inside the document ready I'm using but my function shouldn't conflict with any of this. I've even tried a separate document ready wrapper around the call to check this but this doesn't work either.

Comment: @KunJ Thanks! How do you mean 'add your code'? Sorry i don't understand.

Comment: He probably meant a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: By the way, do you really need the `.each()`? Your selector is a class, so it will already apply to *each* element.

Comment: @KunJ I'm working on our UAT dev environment so I haven't got a jsfiddle set up. It's a tricky one to duplicate but if this is a stumbling block for people to understand my problem then I might try to create something that duplicates the issue.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I believe the `each()` is looping through the code present inside it to assign the data-XXX atts to the variables. If I remove it no amplience code is pulled in against the modules.

Comment: Back to work. @MrUpsidown is right. Have you got any solution?

Comment: @KunJ No not yet. I'll try to simulate the issue in a fiddle if I can. My function call sat inside the 'after ajax event handler' is also sat inside a document.ready. I'm thinking there could be a conflict going on there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the 'options = $.extend(options);' line and it worked!